# investigating differences in violin right hand technique

Tags: violin, bow

I'm making a powerpoint investigating differences in right hand technique between Fritz Kreisler and Jascha Heifetz. However, I have not been able to find much footage or even live photographs of Kreisler playing, only posed portraits and a few frames from a silent film. Are there any other violinists of Heifetz's generation whose playing styles and techniques were recorded and considered to be Kreisler-esque? Or can you find any live footage of Fritz Kreisler's violin technique?

Comment: Welcome! You might want to make some edits to the question; it's already attracted a vote to close, probably because someone perceives it as the kind of question that is answered by a simple list. Although this isn't specifically mentioned on the page of [topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), we try to discourage it. I disagree with whoever left the vote, though perhaps you'd like to narrow the question a bit. No one was (is) *exactly* like Kreisler; presumably you're looking for violinists *whose right-hand technique* is more similar to Kreisler than to Heifetz.

Comment: And for someone like me, who, although I've studied bow techniques attributed to both Kreisler and Heifetz, can't enumerate the important differences that define their bow hands, maybe it would be nice to spell out those distinctions.

Comment: Gosh, how did you choose this topic? // Have you looked for books and articles that weigh in on this?

Answer (score 1):

https://tarisio.com/cozio-archive/cozio-carteggio/kreislers-violins/
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Tip: don't search his violin technique, search his name.
Edit: For more violinists of Kreisler's era (1910s/early 20th century), George Enescu, Romanian composer

[image]